# Minecraft model transparency glitch in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, transparency

I am working on a minecraft animation where I need to import custom minecraft models.  I did this using Techne and a .tcn to a .obj converter (not sure if this affects anything).  I then Imported the .obj and added a texture. The Alpha layer is transparent in material mode but not in rendered mode. Also it is transparent from one side in material mode but opaque from the other.

P.S. It is a 0 pixel deep model at this point.

[image: cycles nodes]

This is in rendered mode:
[image: rendered image]

This is Material mode:
[image: Material mode]

Answer (score 3):

All you need for a transparent material in cycles is a *Transparent* node, a *Mix* node, and some base shader (*Diffuse* node).

These are the only needed nodes.
[image: cycles nodes for transparent material]
The *Image Texture* node sends the color of the image **only** to the *Diffuse* shader, that is very important (more on that in a bit).
The alpha of the image is used as a mask in the *Fac* socket of the *Mix Shader* node. That *Fac* "mixes" the two *Shader* input sockets, biased on the value in the alpha channel of the image (alpha channel shown below). The *Fac* socket is expecting a range between 0 and 1, and that is exactly what the alpha channel is. Anywhere that is black (a value of zero) the top socket is used, so transparent; like wise anywhere that is white in the alpha channel (a value of one) the bottom socket is shown, the diffuse node and thus the color in the image.

The *Transparent* node adds the transparent component to the material. The color of the *Transparent* node controls how transparent the transparency will be. White (a value of one) is completely transparent, conversely black (a value of zero)  will not be transparent at all, it will render solid black.
This is why you can not plug the image texture in to the transparent node.
Anywhere the image is not pure white will not render transparent if the image is plugged into the transparent node.

[image: alpha and color of image in image texture node]

This is the alpha (on the left) of image in image texture node in the picture above; and (on the right) the output of the nodes pictured above.

---

***Advanced nodes***

[image: more cycles nodes]
Here is a slightly more complicated cycles material. All I'm doing is adding in a glossy component to my material.
Do note though, that even with the extra nodes, it does not change the simple transparency setup.